# Multiple sets of radio button with ng-model and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, laravel-blade

I'm very new to Angular and I have some issues with setting the default option on my radio buttons. I have already checked the other answers and using `$parent` does not solve my issue or I'm using it wrong.

I have a group of radio button which contains 2 input:

```
input type="radio" name="@{{ form.form_id }}_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="$parent.field.field_data.suggested" value="@{{ field.field_data.value_a}}" > @{{ field.field_data.value_a }} <br>
input type="radio" name="@{{ form.form_id }}_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="$parent.field.field_data.suggested" value="@{{ field.field_data.value_b }}"> @{{ field.field_data.value_b }}
```

If the page displays only 1 group(pair) of radio button, it correctly sets the default value for the radio button group. The issue here is, when there are 3 groups (3 pairs) of radio button generated by ng-repeat, it only sets the value of the last group of radio buttons and the other 2 groups are left unchecked or blank.

Is this because the radio buttons are generated using 2 ng-repeats? To help, here is my code.

I have an array `$scope.filtered_forms` which is set by:

```
$scope.filtered_forms[index] = {
      form_id:id,
      fields:[{
             field_data: {field.label,
                          field_suggested:string,
                          value_a:string,
                          value_b:string},
             field_type: radio
             },{
             field_data: {field.label,
                          field_suggested:string,
                          value_a:string,
                          value_b:string},
             field_type radio
             },{
              ...same input as above each object represents a group of radio
             }]
}
```

Basically, `$scope.filtered_forms` contains form objects. In my html file, I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="form in filtered_forms" id="@{{ form.form_id }}">
 <table class="table" id="borderless">
       <tr ng-repeat="field in form.fields">
              <th scope="row" width="35%">@{{ field.field_data.label }}</th>
                 <td>
                    <div  ng-if="field.field_type == 'radio'" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                        <input type="radio" name="@{{ form.form_id }}_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="$parent.field.field_data.suggested" value="@{{ field.field_data.value_a}}" > @{{ field.field_data.value_a }} <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="@{{ form.form_id }}_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="$parent.field.field_data.suggested" value="@{{ field.field_data.value_b }}"> @{{ field.field_data.value_b }}
                    </div>
                 </td>
         </tr>
   /table>
```

This right here produces 2 groups/pairs of radio buttons but only the last group gets a default value. Even when using ng-checked and even without $parent.

Additional info, field_suggested has the same value as value_a or value_b. You can see that the radio button is under 2 ng-repeats. I'm using laravel blade and this html file is inside a modal. I removed some of the html data and property inside the form which does not relate to the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: looking at your code I guess In your second ng-repeat since you are iterating over form.fields for each index it will create two radios with same name,model etc. is that what you want?

Comment: @nikhilmehta yes, it will create 2 radios with the same name and model and this will be 1 group/pair of radio buttons. When I get 3 groups of radio, only the last group will be set by default.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixing many things. I copied your code created a plunker and found that the name for the radio group is not actually form_id_{{$index}} but it has whole object as string. I have changed the code hope it helps you.
See the code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/caJZXe9nkMuJYIRQbH6v?p=preview)
The issue is with your group names why are you using @ in the names. Please remove them it should work fine. Also please see that there are no special characters in the value for name attribute.

```
name="{{ form.form_id }}_{{ $index }}"
```

Comment: Hey, the reason why I added @ is that when dealing with laravel blade, {{value}} refers to a php variable. In order to call angular js variables, it needs @{{value}}.

Comment: in that case check for the name of the radio button in developer tool if it contains any special character if yes probably that is the cause that you are getting the behavior you are experiencing. If not what does it contain?

Comment: I'll check it out. But currently,using my code it will display `name="26_1"`.

Comment: Changed the underscore to a word resulting to `name="26test1"` and it is still not working.

Comment: can you please create plunker. It will be easy to help you.